# database.php settings for CodeIgniter and Parse Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, parse-platform, parse-server

Has anyone ever used CodeIgniter + Parse Server? I would like to use the two in conjunction but I don't know what to do with the settings in the database.php file.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'root';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = '';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple database in codeigniter, Just add below lines in same file database.php

```
$db['second_db']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['second_db']['username'] = 'mysql_username';
$db['second_db']['password'] = 'mysql_password';
$db['second_db']['database'] = 'admin';  
// More config in same way, if required
```

Access default database:

```
$this->load->database();
$query = $this->db->query();
```

Access the second database

```
$second_db= $this->load->database('second_db', TRUE);
$query = $second_db->query();
```